# Android SDK MonkeyRunner broken?

Tags: monkeyrunner, android-sdk-tools

I've been having some troubles gettin MonkeyRunner working. So far, we've tried 3 different computers and every android device we could get our hands on.

the result is the same:

```
com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.main(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:203)
110715 16:59:55.819:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] Script
terminated due to an exception
110715 16:59:55.819:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]Traceback
(most recent call last):
File "/Users/lorinbeer/projects/phonegapminer/monkeyrun.py", line 10, in <module>
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:182)
at com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice.<init>(AdbMonkeyDevice.java:68)
at com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbBackend.waitForConnection(AdbBackend.java:100)
at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(MonkeyRunner.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is running on osx, the phone is a Nexus S.

The python looks like:

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
```

I've tried this from a .py file, as well as from the interactive interpreter. I've also tried calling waitForConnection with the timeout and device id arguments, all with the same results.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

--UPDATE--
The device is connected, on, and enabled for development. The issue with monkeyrunner seems to be limited to osx, and might have to do with jdk on osx, and might not be an issue with monkeyrunner itself.

Comment: 1) Is the device on and the screen is unlocked?
2) Are you using the monkeyrunner interpreter and not python?
3) Are there no other devices connected to your computer?

Comment: 1) yes the device is on, if the device wasn't on, monkeyrunner waitforconnection *waits for a connection* 2) as specified in the question, I am using the monkeyrunner interpreter. 3) there is a single device connected to the computer

Answer (score 0):

Please verify your device 'USB debugging' is set to true.
You would find it under:
settings->application->development

Answer (score 0):

type "adb devices" command in terminal 
if it lists any device, then Monkeyrunner.waitForConnection() should not fail.
if device not listed, check if the usb driver is installed properly.